# Add masonry to my infinite scroll method

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I have my custom made infinite scroll script, which makes use of an ajax call:

```
    $(function(){

    var fetching = false;
    var $container = $('#content_home');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.wrdLatest',
            columnWidth:15
        });
    });


    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var bufferzone = $(window).scrollTop() * 0.20;
        if (!fetching && ($(window).scrollTop() + bufferzone > ($(document).height()- $(window).height()-1) && $(".wrdLatest:last").attr("id") != 1)){

        $('.loading').fadeIn(250);
        lastPostFunc();

        }       
    }); 

    function lastPostFunc() 
    { 
        fetching = true;
        $.post("/ajax/loadmore.php?lastid="+$(".wrdLatest:last").attr("id"),

        function(data){
            if (data != "") {
                $container.masonry( 'appended', data, true );
                //setTimeout(function(){$(".wrdLatest:last").after(data);},1000);
                setTimeout(function(){fetching = false;},2000);
                $('.loading').delay(1000).fadeOut(250);
            }
        });
    };  

});
```

I also have implemented the masonry script. Now I would like to make the new content, which is loaded after scrolling, appended to the webpage by using the masonry call:

```
 function(data){
        if (data != "") {
            $container.masonry( 'appended', data, true );
            //setTimeout(function(){$(".wrdLatest:last").after(data);},1000);
            setTimeout(function(){fetching = false;},2000);
            $('.loading').delay(1000).fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
```

but the part:

```
 $container.masonry( 'appended', data, true );
```

doesn't seem to work. Before I've implemented masonry, I used my own method:

```
 //setTimeout(function(){$(".wrdLatest:last").after(data);},1000);
```

This works quite well.

What am I doing wrong in the masonry call?

Demo: http://acc.itemmized.com

It seems like the data is loaded "OVER" the old content... and it is not in a masonry layout...